# When is this going to be executed in Python?

Tags: python

Let's say for a moment that I have the following module in python:

```
class Foo(object):
    pass

def foofunc():
    pass

foofunc()
```

Will `foofunc()` (I mean the last statement) ever be executed if I choose to `import` the module instead of executing it directly?

Comment: Isn't trying this is faster than asking on SO? :)

Comment: @reclosedev Not really, because I am working on a project at the moment, and trying it involves seriously screwing up if something goes wrong. You will argue that I can always revert the changes, but the whole matter is psychological. Fear is very demotivating in this case.

Comment: I'm just sayning, that creating two files: ``foo.py`` with above code, and ``bar.py`` with ``import foo`` is faster than asking it.

Comment: @reclosedev you just made me feel bad about myself :-$

Comment: I recommend that developers live by "Suck it and see." idioms.thefreedictionary.com/suck+it+and+see -- meaning, write small test cases and see what happens.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it will be executed on first import.

Comment: Oh gee, thanx mate. Because I thought it would never be executed, unless I executed the module directly.

Comment: Nlight, if you want your script to work either as a library or an executable, you can use the ['if name equals main' idiom](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)

Comment: @ColonelPanic I do know about that, but thanx for the info anyway.

Comment: Well, the idiom exists for a reason, right? :)